# Count points in polygon (weighted) in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis, point-in-polygon, analysis

In QGIS 2 you could perform a weighted point within a polygon layer using `Processing toolbox > Vector Analysis > Count points in polygon (weighted)`.

I could well be missing something, but I can't find the same function in QGIS 3 (screenshot below). Has it been superseded by another function?

Maybe it requires a plugin?

[image: Absence of weighted count point function in QGIS3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think **the weight** just become optional and hidden inside the ["Count points in polygon"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectoranalysis.html#count-points-in-polygon), see

[image: Count_points_in_polygon]